# Issue binding to ListBox WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I'm try to display three different values within a listbox using hub tile and two textblocks. right now only two of the three items appear. The release `url` and release  `name` and the third item `artistName` is not showing up. I am using a webclient to download the JSON data. Here is my current setup.

First my Classes

```
public class NewReleasesCharts 
{
    //public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
    public ResultHome results = new ResultHome();
    public IEnumerator<ResultHome> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.results.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class ResultHome
{
    public List<FeaturedReleases> featuredReleases { get; set; }

    //public List<FeaturedCharts> featuredCharts { get; set; }
    //public List<TopDownloads> topdownloads { get; set; }
    //public List<MostPopularReleases> mostPopularReleases { get; set; }
    //public List<Components> components { get; set; }

    internal IEnumerator<ResultHome> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class FeaturedReleases
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public List<ReleaseArtist> artists { get; set; }
    public ReleaseImage images { get; set; }
}

public class ReleaseArtist
{
    public int artistID { get; set; }
    public string artistName { get; set; }
}

public class ReleaseImage
{
    //public ReleaseSmall small { get; set; }
    public ReleaseMedium medium { get; set; }
    public ReleaseLarge large { get; set; }
}

public class ReleaseMedium
{
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string secureUrl { get; set; }
}

public class ReleaseLarge
{
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string secureUrl { get; set; }
}
```

xaml

```
                <ListBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="listRelease" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <toolkit:HubTile Source="{Binding images.large.url}" Margin="10" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Width="173" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding artists.artistName}" Width="173" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

and the code behind

```
public void jsonHome_GetDataCompleted(object snder, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    NewReleasesCharts homeData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewReleasesCharts>(e.Result);

    const int limit = 6;

    this.listRelease.ItemsSource = homeData.results.featuredReleases.Take(limit);
}
```

The JSON string can be viewed by inserting the api:http://api.beatport.com/catalog/3/beatport/home, into a [JSON formatter](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/). Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Second listbox bound to Artists

```
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Artists}">
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding artistName}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>    
                </ListBox>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was finally able to figure it out. I bound `artists` to a nested listbox and was able to get the layout I wanted. Here's the code.

```
                    <ListBox x:Name="listRelease" Grid.Row="0" >
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <toolkit:HubTile Source="{Binding images.large.url}" Margin="10" IsFrozen="True" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Width="173" />
                                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding artists}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Margin="10,0,0,0"  Width="173" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListBox>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the output showing errors?
I don't think the property artists.artistName exists since it is a List?

Answer (score 0):

Artists is a list. You have to bind it to a list control (eg. a ListBox or ItemsPanel).

Other possibility: To show only the first artist in the list use this syntax:

```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding artists[0].artistName}" Width="173" />
```

Comment: sorry but what do you mean by binding it to a list control?

Comment: Can i use my existing lisbox or do i have to create a new one? Sorry for all the questions, i'm still new to this.

Comment: you have to write Artists in your binding in lowercase "artists"

Answer (score 0):

You have a capitalization issue when binding `ItemSource` to `Artists`.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Artists}">
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding artistName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>    
</ListBox>
```

However, your `FeaturedReleases` class defines `artists` and not `Artists`.

```
public class FeaturedReleases
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public List<ReleaseArtist> artists { get; set; }
    public ReleaseImage images { get; set; }
}
```

In keeping with your still, you should change the binding to `artists`

Comment: Still not working. Do you think something is wrong with my classes?

Comment: @nos9 - No clue. Do you see any binding errors in the output window? Clean and upload your source tree somewhere. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @nos9 - Yea, that doesn't do much for me.

Comment: @nos9 - Oh wait. Its not `artistName` its just `name` for the `ReleaseArtist` class.

Comment: @nos9- *shrug* Doesn't work is a pretty vague issue. It could be one or dozens of issues.

Comment: I understand. I won't waste anymore of your time. I'll go back over things to see if i missed something. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx), so instead of public `List<ReleaseArtist> artists { get; set; }` there should be `public ObservableCollection<ReleaseArtist> artists { get; set; }` because for me it seems to after you receive the artists from the internet the UI is not updated with those artists.

Check this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365.aspx